# Uniquely constrain table to allow only one true value per unique team with liquibase

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I have an sql join table storing members of a team.  The team and people tables already exist, the team_members table joins these two.

The team members table also includes one other boolean column, team_lead, which represents the leader for a given team.  There can only be one leader per team, shocking I know :).

I want to add a unique constraint to ensure only one team lead exists per team.  essentially I want to ensure that per unique value of the team_id column only one row with a true value may exist in the team_lead column, but any number of rows may exist with false for team_lead.

I would like to add a second constraint, that prevents deleting a team_lead from the team_member database, the team_lead value must be set to false prior to the row being deletable.

It looked like partial keys may be the solution, however, I honestly am not familar with them, nor am I certain that liquibase allows using them.  I don't expect the full sql, but can someone help me out with understanding what tool I should be using and why to enforce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a boolean to the TeamMembers table, add a lead_team_member column to the team table, which will reference the TeamMember record for the member who is the leader.

No need for a tricky constraint, and you can use appropriate foreign keys to prevent the deletion of a TeamMember record that is the lead for a Team.

Comment: That is a good point, except I would prefer not to modify existing tables our code depends on if possible.  I see how your approach makes more sense but, for lack of a better way of phrasing it how 'bad' would the above approach be compared to what you suggested?  Is not wanting to modify tables already being utilized due to expense of modifying existing java code I don't technically own (but could modify if I had to) sufficient justification for not doing it the way you suggested?

Comment: I don't think that you'd ever regret having a correct data model, and your current model has "technical debt" written all over it.